# Domain Driven Design and Ubiquitous Language

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've been reading a bit about DDD and trying to understand it but have a question about Ubiquitous Language.  Isn't it true that in any system, regardless of whether it's DDD or some other philosophy, you should always use proper domain language in your code?

I know there are exceptions for example where the domain uses legacy language.  For a contrived example, if a horse racing expert talks about the starting gate for the horses and says they are called "First gate", "Duo Gate", "Trio Gate", "Forth Gate" etc., you might want to simplify your domain language by calling them Gate1, Gate2, Gate3 and Gate4.  In this case you are effectively redesigning the language in a better way (in your opinion).

But that aside, in my years of development I have never felt the urge to use anything other than domain language in my code.  And so would it be right to say the rule of Ubiquitous Language is really a rule for all development and not restricted or "invented" by DDD?

Answer (score 1):

I think the point Eric Evans is trying to drive home is not to let your model get out-of sync with the ubiquitous language. Let's say that at first a developer may call it First Gate and later find that the domain experts call it "Starting Gate" (I have no idea) but to make sure to go back to the code and take the effort to rename the entity and all references.

Sure it's good practice in all programming endeavors, but it is essential in DDD, which is why it gets special focus.

Comment: It might not always be pragmatic to rename a table name for example